# .NET / React App not serving /.well-known/filename

Tags: reactjs, .net, azure

I'm trying to setup Apple Pay via Stripe, which requests access to a file to verify domain ownership. The problem I'm having is that this file has no extension, so either React, Azure or my .NET application does not like it!

I've tried various solutions to date within the web.config but to no avail.

The file in question is: `/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association`

My project is a .NET project running a React SPA. I've added the file mentioned above to the `/public` folder, too.
I can access `.txt` files in the same folder, so the path/folder is accessible - It seems to be a problem with the lack of extension.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve this with the following, and ensuring the ./well-known and subfiles are in my project root.

```
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, @".well-known")),
        RequestPath = new PathString("/.well-known"),
        DefaultContentType = "application/json",
        ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
    });
```